# $x^2-x+A$ is prime for $0 \le x < A$ if and only if $1-4A$ is a Heegner number

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Many people know that the polynomial $x^2 - x + 41$ is prime until $x = 41$. In fact, it is the largest integer $A$ such that the quadratic $x^2 - x + A$ is prime for all $0 \leq < x < A$. I want to find a proof for this fact. Online, I found that it is equivalent to $1-4A$ being a Heegner number (or $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{1-4A})$ being a UFD. However, I could not find an English proof for the fact. Could anybody help me out?

Comment: There are several equivalent statements in Serre's *Lectures on the Mordell-Weil theorem*, A.2 ff with three approaches to the class number $1$ problem in the Appendix.

Comment: I give a quick proof of Rabinowitz (1913), this might be what you want to know. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289338/is-the-notorious-n2-n-41-prime-generator-the-last-of-its-type/289357#289357

Comment: This is proved in Chapter 11 of Pollack's *A conversational introduction to algebraic number theory*, which is free online. A link is on the author's website: http://pollack.uga.edu/

Answer (score 3):

See Cohn's book "Advanced Number Theory", chapter 9, section 8 "the famous polynomial $x^2+x+q$".

See also http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LuckyNumberofEuler.html

Comment: Sign $+$ or $-$ before $x$?

Comment: Yes, good point. Note that $(x+1)^2-(x+1)=x^2+x$, which suggest a change of variables!

Answer (score 0):

From http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Prime-GeneratingPolynomial.html,

> Conway, J. H. and Guy, R. K. ["The Nine Magic Discriminants"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/038797993X). In The Book of Numbers. New York: Springer-Verlag, pp. 224-226, 1996.

has an English proof.

Comment: I checked this book already. It states the fact without proof or motivation.